# jquery Isotope - scroll to center clicked enlarged item

Tags: jquery-isotope, scrollto

I'm new here, (and no coder, I am working as Architect) but over the last months I've browsed this place very often to find solutions to several problems I encountered while making a new website for our architectural office. 
The site is already online, but I still have a problem I like to get solved to get it work like I would want to.

In the site I used jquery Isotope on several places and in different ways. but for our news section I used isotope to show the newsitems available. The newsitems are populated from a xml-file, and when you click the image, the newsitem will enlarge and extra text info is added, aswell as imagebuttons and more. 
Because the items are enlarging there is need for a re-layout of the raster, and frequently news-items are moving out of view after re-layouting.

To solve that problem I want to scroll to the destination item, and focus on it again. I used Ariel Flesher's Jquery.ScrolTo plugin to get this problem solved (which is working great on the portfolio part of our site).
The problem is that I can't figure out which coordinates to scroll to. Currently I am using the top of the used image as placeholder, and that seems fine, but when I am setting my scroll command after the re-layout command it's still scrolling to the old place of the image, not to the place after re-layouting.

So in short my question is, How can I get the new coordinates after relayout, to provide them to the scrollfunction?

```
//          change newsitem from small to big
        $container.delegate('.element.crid_1 .img_container','click',function(){
            /* img src */               
            var ori = $('img', this).attr('src');
            if(ori != undefined){
                var string = $('img', this).attr('src');
                var bigpicture = string.truncate(-6)
                $('img', this).attr('src',bigpicture +'01.jpg');
                $('img', this).attr('width',512);
                $('img', this).attr('height',512);
            } 
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('featured not_featured');
            txt_height = $(this).parent().find('.text').height();                           
            new_height = manage_txt_heights(txt_height);    
            $(this).parent().find('.text').css({"height" : new_height + "px" });

            $container.isotope('reLayout');

            var imgoffset=$('img', this).offset().top ;
            var calculation = '+='+imgoffset+'px';
            $('#nieuwswrapper').scrollTo(calculation,800);
        });
```

above code is what I use to enlarge the newsitem, after the re-layout command, I have put the lines for the scroll behaviour. where the value 800 is the scrollingspeed.

The entire 'working' webpage is available here [website newssection](http://www.bartduvekot.nl/nieuws.html)

thanks in Advance for any advice.
Jan

Comment: That link is broken.  I believe you mean: http://www.bartduvekot.nl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can activate ItemPositionData:

```
$('#container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element',
  itemPositionDataEnabled: true
})
// log position of each item
.find('.element').each(function(){
  var position = $(this).data('isotope-item-position');
  console.log('item position is x: ' + position.x + ', y: ' + position.y  );
});
```

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled

Comment: I can't see a single mention of the attribute `itemPositionDataEnabled` in the documentation. Is that something, that's been deprecated?